# react-native-dropdown-picker don't show the icon

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I'm beginner in React Native and I need some help! :)
I'm using react-native-dropdown-picker on my project to show a list of options. The list is working, but dosen't showing the icon that indicate  tha it's a list.

There is the image like I see in my simulator:
[The exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE89Q.png)

Can some one helps me?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install react-native-vector-icons and react-native link react-native-vector-icons, to render its icons.

Comment: I have done this, but the same problem happen. Must I import in my page like this:

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

thanks for answer

Comment: any icons in your project that is visible, can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, just this I can't see! When I use the picker don't show any icon. :(

Comment: try this cmd -> react-native link react-native-vector-icons

it should solve your problem

Comment: That is it, man! It's worked and the icon become showing. Great job!
Thanks for help.